# Missing /__data in SvelteKit after building

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a Svelte Kit app, I use vite to build it.
When I run `npx vite build` and `npx vite preview`, it works fine.

When I take the result of the build and serve it on a HTTP Server, I have this error:

`GET /__data.json?x-sveltekit-trailing-slash=1&x-sveltekit-invalidated=1" Error (404): "Not found"`

I don't know where this come from.

Anyone has any clue?

Thanks!